# Splitting string in c#

Tags: c#, .net, regex, asp.net-mvc-2, string

I have a `string` getting posted to my MVC action that looks like this:

```
[{"property":"radius","value":"twentyfive"},{"property":"latlng","value":"40.036218,-75.51381100000003"}]
```

I need the radius value of `twentyfive` in this case, but could be anything, and also each latitude and longitude number, so they would be `40.036218` and `-75.51381100000003` here.

so something like:

```
string filter = "[{\"property\":\"radius\",\"value\":\"twentyfive\"},{\"property\":\"latlng\",\"value\":\"40.036218,-75.51381100000003\"}]";
string radius = //whatever i need to do;
double lat = //whatever i need to do;
double lng = //whatever i need to do;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Hook yourself up with some JSON.NET and simply deserialize the JSON string into an object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a class like this

```
public class PropertyValue
{
    public string property {get; set;}
    public string value  {get; set;}
}
```

and use [`JavaScriptSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx)

```
string inputString = @"[{""property"":""radius"",""value"":""twentyfive""},{""property"":""latlng"",""value"":""40.036218,-75.51381100000003""}]";
IList<PropertyValue> propertyValueList = new JavaScriptSerializer()
        .Deserialize<IList<PropertyValue>>(inputString);
Console.WriteLine(propertyValueList.Single(p  => p.property == "radius").value);
```